# ionic 3 angular 4 alert component call to the main component when it makes an action

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a main component and an [alert](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) `ionic 3` component.

What I'm trying to do, is to make the main component wait until the accept button from the alert component is tapped. After that, the main component should get the data of the alert component.

My question is if a chained promise waiting for the accept button tap is a good approach to do that or if there's anything much better?

Here below I paste the code that tries to do that:

**alertComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'unit-prompt'
})
export class UnitPromptComponent {

    public quantity: number;
    private hasAccepted: boolean = false;

  constructor(
        private alertCtrl: AlertController
    ) {}

    public displayPrompt(): Promise<number> {
        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Cantidad',
      message: "Agrega el número de platos",
      inputs: [{
                name: 'title',
                placeholder: 'Cantidad',
                type: 'number'
            }],
      buttons: [{
                text: 'Cancelar',
                handler: data => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
      }, {
                text: 'Agregar',
                handler: data => {
                    this.setQuantity(data);
                }
            }]
    });

    prompt.present();

        return this.checkIfPromptIsAccepted()
            .then(() => {
                return this.getQuantity();
            });
    }

    public setQuantity(quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.hasAccepted = true;
    }

    private checkIfPromptIsAccepted() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.hasAccepted) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                // trying to do a chained promise till this.hasAccepted is true
                resolve(this.checkIfPromptIsAccepted());
            }
        });

    }

    public getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }
}
```

**mainComponent.ts**

```
private doPrompt(dishName) {
    this.prompt.displayPrompt()
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            // do some stuff because the accept button has tapped
            this.navCtrl.pop();
        }).catch((e) => {
            throw new Error('sth went wrong');
        });
}
```

Comment: The docs you linked to literally discuss the topic of routing after dismissal. They even discuss a more general situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public displayPrompt(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Cantidad',
        message: "Agrega el número de platos",
        inputs: [{
          name: 'title',
          placeholder: 'Cantidad',
          type: 'number'
        }],
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Cancelar',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
            resolve(-1);
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Agregar',
          handler: data => {
            resolve(data);
          }
        }]
      });

      prompt.present();
      prompt.onDidDismiss(() => {
        resolve(-1);
      })
    })
  }
```

It will work. But i think create a component for alert is not a good idea.